# What's the best way to actively sync two folders across two network locations?

Tags: windows, synchronization

I have two Windows 2003 servers on two network locations, and the folders are supposed to have the same content at any given time. Basically, whenever a file is written to one of the folders it needs to be written to the corresponding folder on the other machine. What's the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You want to use [DFS Replication](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc773238(v=ws.10).aspx) for this.

The link provided is for 2012, but DFS-R was first introduced in 2003. It will meet your needs without all of the bells and whistles of the newer versions.

Answer (score 0):

[SyncToy](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15155)

You can script it, so you could make scheduled job out of it, running once every minute or so.